# Read Text File from user input

Tags: prolog

```
find :-
    write('Enter File Name: '),
    see(File).
    seen.
```

Now the user can input the text file name and read the text file by using see(File) predicate.
But see(File) must follow the format like see('File.txt'), so how can i read a text file base on user input file name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find:-
    write('Enter File Name: '),
    read(File),
    processFind(File).
processFind(File):-
    write('Enter A Name: '),
    read(Name),
    see(File),
    repeat,
    read(Term),
    processCheck(Term, Name),
    seen.
processCheck(end_of_file, _):-
    write('Record Not Found'), !.
processCheck(Term, Name):-
    Term = Name -> (write('Record Found'), !).
```

This is ***correct*** answer that i had finally get it.
Enter a file name including a single quotation and then go for ***check*** whether the name is ***exist*** in the file or not.

**True** will return Record found **else** record not found.

Answer (score 0):

To capture the input from the user you use the read() predicate:

```
 read(X).
```

So you can try this:

```
find :-
    write('Enter File Name: '),
    read(File),
    see(File),
    seen.
```

Comment: but the output will be like this
Enter File Name: 
|: 'xxx.txt'

and i want like this 
Enter File Name: 'xxx.txt'

Comment: i can assume the users will not input the file name with single quotations. Thus, how can i put the single quotation for it.?

Comment: I don't have my prolog system installed right now to test but can you use string_concat/3 to concatenante the single quotes?